# what does mean with AccountExpirationDate?

Tags: asp.net

what does mean with AccountExpirationDate ?does this mean that accolunt will be deleted after this period?i want to delete the account programaticlly after a specific period.

here my code snippet :

```
    void _createUserAccount(String User, String Pass, DateTime expirationDate)
{
    PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
    System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(pc);
    u.SetPassword(Pass);
    u.Name = User;
    u.Description = "New User";
    u.UserCannotChangePassword = true;
    u.PasswordNeverExpires = false;
    u.AccountExpirationDate = expirationDate;

    u.Save();
}
```

and in page_load ;i am calling this method:

```
_createUserAccount(Request.QueryString["UserName"].ToString(), Request.QueryString["Password"].ToString(), Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["ExpireDate"].ToString()));
```

but after the period ended ;i checked the users account on my PC and found the account still exists.

any idea??

Comment: thanks for your reply ;but is there any way to delete this account programatically after the expired date?

Answer (score 0):

No, it just means that the account will be deactivated and placed in an "expired" state after the given date.  If you really want the account deleted, you will have to do that manually.

Comment: What is the 'expired' state?  I don't see it anywhere.  Is it different from disabled?  Is it different from having an expired password?  Does a user have the authority to un-expire their own account (like an expired password)?